# How to read a text string into the urllib data parameter?

Tags: python, urllib

I am following [these](https://www.rcsb.org/pdb/software/static.do?p=/software/webservices/search_nmr.jsp) guidelines (although they are for python2) to perform a search [here](https://www.rcsb.org/pdb/software/rest.do), and the query I need is:

```
queryText = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orgPdbQuery>
<queryType>org.pdb.query.simple.TreeEntityQuery</queryType>
<description>TaxonomyTree Search for OTHER SEQUENCES</description>
<t>1</t>
<n>694009</n>
<nodeDesc>OTHER SEQUENCES</nodeDesc>
</orgPdbQuery>
"""
```

I know this query is right, because when I enter it into the second link 'Sample XML Queries' (selecting 'Source Organism Browser (NCBI)', i get an output (this is just the start of it):

```
383 results

1Q2W:1 1QZ8:1 1SSK:1 1UJ1:1 1UK2:1 1UK3:1 1UK4:1 1UW7:1 1WNC:1 1WOF:1 1WYY:1 1XAK:1 1YO4:1 1YSY:1 1Z1I:1 1Z1J:1 1ZV7:1 1ZV8:1 1ZV8:2 1ZVA:1 1ZVB:1 2A5A:1 2A5I:1 2A5K:1 2ACF:1 2AHM:1 2AHM:2 2AJF:2 2ALV:1 2AMD:1 2AMQ:1 2BEQ:1 2BEQ:2 2BEZ:1 2BEZ:2 2BX3:1 2BX4:1 2C3S:1 2CJR:1 2CME:1 2CME:2 2CME:3 2CME:4 2D2D:1 2DD8:3 2DUC:1 2FAV:1 2FE8:1 2FXP:1 2FYG:1 2G9T:1 2GA6:1 2GDT:1 2GHV:1 2GHW:1 2GIB:1 2GRI:1 2GT7:1 2GT8:1 2GTB:1 2GX4:1 2GZ7:1 2GZ8:1 2GZ9:1 2H2Z:1 2H85:1 2HOB:1 2HSX:1 2IDY:1 2JW8:1 2JZD:1 2JZE:1 2JZF:1 2K7X:1 2K87:1 2KAF:1 2KQV:1 2KQW:1 2KYS:1 2LIZ:1 2MM4:1 2OFZ:1 2OG3:1 2OP9:1 2OZK:1 2PWX:1 2Q6G:1 2QC2:1 2
```

I now want to replicate this search in python, so I wrote this:

```
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/rest/search'


queryText = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orgPdbQuery>
<queryType>org.pdb.query.simple.TreeEntityQuery</queryType>
<description>TaxonomyTree Search for OTHER SEQUENCES</description>
<t>1</t>
<n>694009</n>
<nodeDesc>OTHER SEQUENCES</nodeDesc>
</orgPdbQuery>
"""

encoded_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(queryText).encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req,data=encoded_data) as f:
        resp = f.read()
        print(resp)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/slowat/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 892, in urlencode
    raise TypeError
TypeError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_pdbs_from_rcsb.py", line 19, in <module>
    encoded_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(queryText).encode('utf-8')
  File "/Users/slowat/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 900, in urlencode
    "or mapping object").with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/slowat/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 892, in urlencode
    raise TypeError
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping obj
```

Could someone demonstrate how to get this code to work?

Update 1: I also tried:

```
url = 'http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/rest/search'
d = dict(queryType='org.pdb.query.simple.TreeEntityQuery',n='694009')
f = urllib.parse.urlencode(d)
f = f.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url,f)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as f:
       resp = f.read()
       print(resp)
```

which has the output:

```
'Problem creating Query from XML: Content is not allowed in prolog.\nqueryType=org.pdb.query.simple.TreeEntityQuery&n=694009\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `urlencode` function expects a dictionary of `key: value` pairs. There is no need to use this function here, since you're submitting XML directly to the service. The `data` parameter should be bytes, so make sure to mark your `queryText` as a byte sequence instead of a string (this is specific for Python 3 - the `b` before `"""` marks it as a byt sequence and not as a plain string):

```
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/rest/search'

queryText = b"""
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orgPdbQuery>
<queryType>org.pdb.query.simple.TreeEntityQuery</queryType>
<description>TaxonomyTree Search for OTHER SEQUENCES</description>
<t>1</t>
<n>694009</n>
<nodeDesc>OTHER SEQUENCES</nodeDesc>
</orgPdbQuery>
"""

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req,data=queryText) as f:
        resp = f.read()
        print(resp)
```

This gives the result you expect back in `resp`.

Comment: oh wow thanks, and also thanks for the explanation so I understand it.